# type in url and hit submit in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

is that possible to avoid URL redirection as we do with php or java script, instead it will be like type in URL in browser and then hit submit. 
so it will be like a direct visitor.

can java script do this , or how it will works

Comment: can it worth and more secure?

Comment: i think it worth for me and according to security, i will test and make sure if this approach is secure, but this time i am concern about how i can do this